# C# Counting the number of upper and lower case letters in a string

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, foreach

Hi I've been asked to do a task which calculates the number of vowels, consonants, upper and lower case letters in a string.

I'm having trouble working out upper and lower case letters in a string.
I can successfully count the number of vowels and constants but upper and lower case letters seems to be a pain.

Here's the code:

```
    public void Calculate()
    {
        foreach(string sentence in sentenceList)
        {
            sentences++;

            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
            {
                if (vowelsArray.Contains(sentence[i]))
                {
                    vowels++;
                }
                else if (consonantsArray.Contains(sentence[i]))
                {
                    consonants++;
                }
                else if (char.IsUpper(sentence[i]))
                {
                    upperCaseLetters++;
                }
                else if (char.IsLower(sentence[i]))
                {
                    lowerCaseLetters++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The value for the upper and lower case letters is 0. (It shouldn't be)

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: you can do this using a single line of code to check Upper then use the same single line of code and change it to check Lower 
`var cnt = YourString.Count(c => Char.IsUpper(c))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a chain of `if`/`else` statements and the first condition that is matched (either the vowels or consonants) will prevent any future conditions from being matched.  Break the `if`/`else` chain into 2 chains:

- Vowels vs Consonants
- Uppercase vs Lowercase

See updated code below:

```
    public void Calculate()
    {
        foreach(string sentence in sentenceList)
        {
            sentences++;

            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
            {
                if (vowelsArray.Contains(sentence[i]))
                {
                    vowels++;
                }
                else if (consonantsArray.Contains(sentence[i]))
                {
                    consonants++;
                }

                // the else was removed here!
                if (char.IsUpper(sentence[i]))
                {
                    upperCaseLetters++;
                }
                else if (char.IsLower(sentence[i]))
                {
                    lowerCaseLetters++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are a star! Haha such a simple fix. Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `else` before

```
else if (char.IsUpper(sentence[i]))
```

Because you have two **independent** sets of conditions:

1. Vowel / Consonant
2. UpperCase / LowerCase

Comment: does the OP even need the `else if` to check for lower case?  If the letter is not UpperCase then obviously it will be LowerCase.. so that just needs to be an else statement.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid What if the `sentence[i]` is not a letter? For instance, a space or a punctuation char.

Comment: I can understand that, but this sounds like a homework assignment so I doubt that the string would contain numbers (I know what assume means), but the OP didn't state that they would have to account for anything besides letters.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid You could ask the OP about assumptions. But IMO it has nothing to do with the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

You're only going to hit a single one of those conditions each time through the loop, so if your first two conditions cover every possibility (which is pretty likely, since that covers all vowels and all consonants!) you never reach your third and fourth blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
  string text = "This is Sample";
  int upcount = 0;
  int lowcount = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
  {
   if (char.IsUpper(text[i])) upcount++;
   if (char.IsLower(text[i])) lowcount++;
  }
  Console.Write(upcount);
  Console.Write(lowcount);
```

**EDIT**

In your case change it like this,

```
if (char.IsUpper(sentence[i]))
{
    upperCaseLetters++;
}
else (char.IsLower(sentence[i]))
{
    lowerCaseLetters++;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have in my program, have you tested this and seen result? I'm just getting 0's.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this using [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NRvHLU)

But here is the code that worked for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int upper = 0;
        int lower = 0;

        string upperLowerCase = "This Is A Test";

        char[] splitString = upperLowerCase.ToCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < splitString.Length; i++)
        {
            if(char.IsUpper(splitString[i]))
            {
                upper++;    
            }
            else
            {
                lower++;    
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total Upper Case Letters: " + upper.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Total Lower Case Letters: " +lower.ToString());
    }
}

// Output
// Total Upper Case Letters: 4
// Total Lower Case Letters: 10
```

But in your case you need to separate conditional statements.  One to check for vowels or consonants and the other to check the case of the letter.

So this:

```
else if (char.IsUpper(sentence[i]))
{
    upperCaseLetters++;
}
else if (char.IsLower(sentence[i]))
{
    lowerCaseLetters++;
}
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
if (char.IsUpper(sentence[i]))
{
    upperCaseLetters++;
}
else
{
    lowerCaseLetters++;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly faster version based on Sajeetharan's answer

```
 string text = "This is Sample";
  int upcount = 0;
  int lowcount = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
  {
  if (text[i]>64 && text[i]<91) upcount++;
   else if (text[i]>96 && text[i]<123) lowcount++;
  }
  Console.Write(upcount);
  Console.Write(lowcount);
```